# Kotlin is it possible to delegate function or function parameters?

Tags: kotlin, generics, parameter-passing, kotlin-reflect, kotlin-delegate

I want to have for example:

```
class Foo {
   fun doSomething(arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: Boolean)
}

class FooDelegate {
   //different fun name
   fun execute by Foo::doSomething
}
```

Either with reflection or other way.

What I currently have is:

```
class FooDelegated<R>(
    private val func: KFunction<R>
) {
    fun execute(vararg params: Any) = func.call(*params)
}
```

So that I can call

```
FooDelegated(Foo::doSomething).execute("1", "2", true)
```

However I require to send parameters which are not really know. I would like my compiler to know which parameters can be sent. Else, I can write the following and it won't fail until run time:

```
   FooDelegated(Foo::doSomething).execute("1", "2", "new argument", false)
```

NOTE that I want it to have different names, not by using interfaces.

Comment: How would `fun execute by Foo::doSomething` ever work? You don't even have an instance of `Foo`! Do you expect `execute` to take an extra parameter of `Foo`?

Comment: Also, what is wrong with `fun execute(arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: Boolean) = someFoo.doSomething(arg1, arg2, arg3)`?

Comment: I can't think of any possible way to do this at compile time with annotations. Reflection is useless since that is done at runtime. I think you would need a customized Kotlin compiler to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating `execute()` function, you can create `execute` property and keep a function reference there. Then you can use it almost like it is a function:

```kotlin
class FooDelegate {
    val execute = Foo::doSomething
}

fun main() {
    FooDelegate().execute(Foo(), "hello", "world", true)
}
```

Or:

```kotlin
class FooDelegate {
    private val foo = Foo()
    val execute = foo::doSomething
}

fun main() {
    FooDelegate().execute("hello", "world", true)
}
```

You can also create a wrapper around `KFunction` to hide its properties like `annotations`, `isFinal`, etc., but keep its `operator fun invoke` functionality. This would give you more flexibility on what you can do with these functions. It would also make possible to replace `execute` property with a true `execute()` function. However, you would need to create a separate wrapper per number of properties. It could look like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    delegate(Foo()::doSomething).execute("hello", "world", true)
    delegate(Foo::doSomething).execute(Foo(), "hello", "world", true)
}

fun <P0, P1, P2, R> delegate(func: (P0, P1, P2) -> R) = FunctionDelegate3(func)
fun <P0, P1, P2, P3, R> delegate(func: (P0, P1, P2, P3) -> R) = FunctionDelegate4(func)

class FunctionDelegate3<P0, P1, P2, R>(
    private val func: (P0, P1, P2) -> R
) {
    fun execute(p0: P0, p1: P1, p2: P2): R = func(p0, p1, p2)
}

class FunctionDelegate4<P0, P1, P2, P3, R>(
    private val func: (P0, P1, P2, P3) -> R
) {
    fun execute(p0: P0, p1: P1, p2: P2, p3: P3): R = func(p0, p1, p2, p3)
}
```

Still, it sounds like a very strange thing to do. Like you trying to create programming language inside another programming language.

Comment: Mm I understand however it doesn't work as I need. What I am really looking forward is to send Foo:doSomething as a parameter, so that the Delegate can use execute to call any other function defined as a parameter.

I tryed using a KFunction in the val but it doesn't seem to be able to infer the parameters.

Comment: For example: `Delegate(foo::doSomething).execute("1", "2", false)`  .  I'm exploring some possibilities for an architecture, to create intermediate components without having to create an "empty" class just to have the intermediate component

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about that and creating FunctionN variants, then I thought that even so the argument names won't be identified as the original names, but only as p0, p1, p2, etc ; and will probably be more confusing to devs :P. Thank you anyway!